# Possible to programatically change IIS's SMTP server "Smart Host"

Tags: c#, iis, smtp, windows-server-2008, wmi

I recently discovered a way to audit SMTP emails prior to them actually leaving the SMTP server.  This is accomplished by changing the "Smart Host" value to something that is

1. Named a host that doesn't exist
2. Less than 15 characters
3. Has no periods in the name

[image]

This allows me to view the messages with Outlook Express, check the file attachments, and other programatically generated content through `System.Net.Mail`

I release the messages by changing this to a valid value and restarting the SMTP service.

**Question**

How can I programatically change this value so I can allow for the controlled queueing, audit, and release of these email messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically do this using the IIS WMI Provider. The [SmartHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525732%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property can be found on either the [IIsSmtpService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525824%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or [IIsSmtpServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524936%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) object. On Windows Server 2008 you will need to install IIS 6.0 WMI compatibility. Something like the following should work.

```
public static void ConfigureSmtpHost()
{
    DirectoryEntry smtpServer = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://LOCALHOST/SMTPSVC/1");
    smtpServer.Properties["SmartHost"].Value = "myNewSmartHost";
    smtpServer.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!  One method might be to just create a program that directly edits the Metabase, and then restarts SMTPSVC.  I'm sure there's a way with WMI, but I don't know offhand.

By the way, you might be able to go in the "other" direction by editing your app.config/web.config to drop the files in a folder of your choice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164241.aspx

After you inspect the emails, you can move them to IIS's queue.